# Ubuntu package management that are NOT from repository

Tags: linux, ubuntu, package, apt

I have a question about package management in Ubuntu. I know that there exist standard repositories from which I install software in form of packages. Suppose I want to install some software that don't exist in standard repositories. What should I do? Of course I want to track and manage this software as easy as software from standard repository. What is the canonical way of managing such software on Linux, especially Ubuntu OS? Any answer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manage packages that are installed outside of the standard APT repositories, but not that easy. Packages that are installed with `apt install /path/to/package-downloaded-elsewhere-but-not-from-repo.deb` are not usually receive updates, so you'll only stuck with install and uninstall stuff.